# ANSI-последовательности (ANSI escape sequences)

Tags: c, printf

Как эта магия работает?Может ли этот магически код \033 делать что-то ещё? Это реализовано на уровене ОС или Си так умеет делать?[image: Some magic]

Comment: Это реализовано на уровне устройства (терминала) (в конкретно вашем случае на уровне программы, которая эмулирует терминал). ОС (а тем более язык программирования) не имеют непосредственного отношения к этим ["эскейп-последовательностям"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (а вот за объединением расширения макроса `ESC_` с последующей строкой в одну строковую константу, конечно, стоит компилятор Си)

Comment: @avp прошу прощения, а где-нибудь можно про объединение сток таким вот макросом почитать? Это как-то на уровне стандарта, или же зависит от компилятора?

Comment: Строки объединяются не макросом, а компилятором.  Препроцессор (первая стадия этапа компиляции) просто подставляет текст результата макроса (такого, как `ESC_` в вашем случае) вместо его тела. Прочитать про это, наверное, можно в любом нормальном учебнике. В принципе тут все очень просто. Например, вот в таком `puts("ab" "123" "cde");` компилятор "склеивает" константы и в stdout вы увидите `ab123cde`. От компилятора (imho) это не зависит (впрочем, кроме gcc я давно практически ни чем не пользуюсь)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В свое время это было достаточно популярным средством для вывода в цвете, в разных местах экрана и т.д. и называется это ANSI-последовательностями. Более того, создавались целые движущиеся (!) картины из символов с раскраской :)

Однако, как я понимаю, в первую очередь из-за нереализованности этого в консоли Windows популярность данного средства очень упала.

Приводить здесь полную таблицу ANSI-кодов - не уверен, что это хорошая идея, из-за отсутствия возможности нормального форматирования в ruSO. Но прочесть о них можно, например, в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) или, например, [тут](http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/freebsd/ansi.shtml).

Никакого отношения ни к C, ни тем более к `printf` данная тема не имеет.